# How to check the available VM Sizes in an Azure Region using Azure sdk for go

Tags: azure, go, cloud

I'm trying to get a list of the available vm sizes in a particular region using azure sdk for go. But as of yet I haven't been able to find how i'd do it with the sdk.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks